# Creating a MySql table when activating a plugin in WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, plugins

I'm trying to follow a basic tutorial to create a database table from a plugin being activated in WordPress.

The file below are in my includes/plugins directory - and appear in my Plugins dashboard in WordPress.  I click on the activate link - but the new table, "tf_customer " isn't created.

I can't see where to turn on error checking for PHP scripts (I'm coming from .net).

Can anyone see any issue with the code below, or help advise how I can trace where any errors may be? (Thank you to Lawrence for pointing me to a guide on turning on error logging)

Thanks for any help,

Mark

Filename: DataBase_Plugin.php

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Tait Fitness Tracker Plugin
Author: Mark
Version: 0.0.1
Description: This is a custom Plugin for TF
*/

if ( !defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;

// Act on plugin activation
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, "tf_activate_plugin" );

// Act on plugin de-activation
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, "tf_deactivate_plugin" );

// Activate Plugin
function tf_activate_plugin() {

    // Execute tasks on Plugin activation

    // Insert DB Tables
    init_db_tfplugin();
}

// De-activate Plugin
function tf_deactivate_plugin() {

    // Execute tasks on Plugin de-activation
}

// Initialize DB Tables
function init_db_tfplugin() {

    // Code to create DB Tables
        // WP Globals
    global $table_prefix, $wpdb;

    // Customer Table
    $tfcustomerTable = $table_prefix . 'tf_customer';

    // Create Customer Table if not exist
    if( $wpdb->get_var( "show tables like '$tfcustomerTable'" ) != $tfcustomerTable ) {

        // Query - Create Table
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE '$tfcustomerTable' (";
        $sql .= " 'id' int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment, ";
        $sql .= " 'email' varchar(500) NOT NULL, ";
        $sql .= " 'fname' varchar(500) NOT NULL, ";
        $sql .= " 'sname' varchar(500), ";
        $sql .= " 'line1' varchar(500) NOT NULL, ";
        $sql .= " 'line2' varchar(500), ";
        $sql .= " 'line3' varchar(500), ";
        $sql .= " 'city' varchar(150) NOT NULL, ";
        $sql .= " 'state' varchar(150), ";
        $sql .= " 'area' varchar(15), ";
        $sql .= " 'country' varchar(5) NOT NULL, ";
        $sql .= " PRIMARY KEY 'customer_id' ('id') ";
        $sql .= ") ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;";

        // Include Upgrade Script
        require_once( ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    
        // Create Table
        dbDelta( $sql );
    }

}
```

Comment: *Define absolute path to avoid direct access* should be commented out.. to enable errors read the docs https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 0):

syntax was all correct, but in the SQL statement, I was using an apostrophe instead of ` -updated that, and now working!